# MapServer very weak performance vs. GeoServer - Why?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wms, mapserver, performance

I search for a good WMS server that support **PostGIS** at the end I found **MapServer** as the fastest and best choice.

Every performance test say it's faster than **GeoServer** because of its native compiled code.

Then when we developed our server side using **MapScript**  (the MapServer extension for PHP).

When we did some benchmark on server and compared it with GeoServer and

**Wow! MapServer is 2 to 3 times slower than GeoServer.**

We also repeat the experiment with MapServer CGI and results not changed.

Our experiment environments:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- MapServer version 6.0.3 (MS4W 3.0.6) (MS4W/PHP Mapscript)
- GeoServer 2.7
- PostGIS 2.1
- PostgreSQL 9.4

The PHP code which used to render tiles and used as WMS server:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_REQUEST['layerId']))
    die('Layer Is Not Valid');

$layerId=(int)$_REQUEST['layerId'];

$map=new mapObj(null);
$map->setFontSet(realpath("lib\\server-side\\fonts.list"));
$map->setConfigOption("MS_ERRORFILE",__DIR__.("\\ms_error.log"));

$map->metadata->set('wms_enable_request','GetCapabilities GetMap GetFeatureInfo');
$map->metadata->set('wms_getmap_formatlist','image/png,png,png8,png24');
$map->setProjection("init=epsg:4326");

$layer = new LayerObj($map);

$layer->set('labelcache', MS_ON);
$layer->setProcessing('LABEL_NO_CLIP=FALSE');
$layer->setProcessing('FORCE2D=YES');

$layer->set('name', "MasterLayer");
$layer->set('status', MS_DEFAULT );

$layer->setConnectionType(MS_POSTGIS);
$layer->set('connection', "user=postgres password=psgpass dbname=map host=127.0.0.1 port=5432");
$layer->set('data', "geodata from geo_data as subquery using SRID=-1 using unique id ");

$layer->set('type', MS_LAYER_POLYGON);

$class = new ClassObj( $layer );

$style = new StyleObj( $class );
$style->color->setRGB(255,0,0);
$style->set('opacity',100);

$request = new Owsrequestobj();
$request->loadparams();
$request->setparameter('REQUEST', 'GetMap');
$request->setparameter('LAYERS', 'MasterLayer');
$request->setparameter('FORMAT', 'png8');

ms_ioinstallstdouttobuffer();
$map->owsdispatch($request);

$contenttype = ms_iostripstdoutbuffercontenttype();

if (!empty($contenttype))
{
    header('Content-type: $contenttype');
    ms_iogetStdoutBufferBytes();
}
else 
    echo "Fail to render!";
ms_ioresethandlers();
?>
```

DataBase Data Projection: **EPSG:4326**

Does anybody know why GeoServer is much faster when it isn't compiled natively? Am I missed something?

Comment: potentially relevant question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808273/slow-performance-from-mapserver). Also, [this](http://www.slideshare.net/DonnyV/wms-performance-tests-map-server-vs-geo-server) presentation linked to in one of the comments. FastCGI is mentioned frequently.

Comment: the first link really no i saw it before. The Second One Can Help But Most Of Those Optimization  I Applied Before

Comment: we need to know what sort of data you have, how it is styled, how you configured the two programs etc

Comment: @iant if you mean data base its Geometry and Polygon Type and data come from postgres database.
If it help i can put php and data sample here.
I really think mapserver should be faster and I did some thing wrong or some driver is missing or the version is too old

Comment: both programs has a layer with EPSG4326 and feed by same table. Every polygon have a simple fill color and border. Actually I disable all options in mapserver to make it faster but performance didn't change too much and still the geoserver is the absolute winner.

Comment: You might find this useful. http://www.esdm.co.uk/mapserver-and-geoserver-and-tilecache-comparison-serving-ordnance-survey-raster-maps

Comment: @JohnBarça thanks but this test a bit old 3 years ago and geoserver seems to be changed a lot

Comment: I would like to get your source data with SLD and mapfile you have been using as well as the details about how you measured the performance. I would also forget at least in the first tests the php mapscript code and run MapServer directly as a WMS server.

Comment: MapServer version 6.0.3 (MS4W 3.0.6) (MS4W/PHP MapScript) is 32-bit MapServer and Apache.  Is your GeoServer 2.7 a 64-bit install?

Answer (score 6):

According to a [recent comparison](https://web.archive.org/web/20190626045452/http://mapsurfernet.com/blog/benchmarking-mapping-toolkits-in-tile-seeding) of different mapping engines in performing tile seeding (see Section 4.3), MapServer should be much faster than GeoServer.

Is there any re-projection of geometries in your rendering stack?

An old version of MapServer might have the [same issue](https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/issues/785) with proj4 lib as Mapnik had.

Comment: About re-projection I'm not sure data in database(postgres) saved with EPSG4326 and map file projection is also is also 4326 .
The server make wms tiles for openlayers 3.

Unfortunately I cant find the binaries' the latest version of mapscript (php) for windows to test performance.

About the proj4 i dont know exactly which version is used (its a dll without details) but from exe it version is:
Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012

Comment: Mapscript exact version: 


MapServer version 6.0.3 (MS4W 3.0.6) 


OUTPUT=GIF OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG OUTPUT=KML SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=
THREADS SUPPORTS=GEOS INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE

Comment: Might be worth trying with a 64 bit version of MapServer (say from GISinternals)

Comment: It doesn't include PHP-MapScript  actually any of their releases !

Comment: according this benchmark, geoserver is faster but mapserver renders nicely: http://www.esdm.co.uk/further-load-testing-of-geoserver-and-mapserver-and-tilecache

Comment: In my limited experience, Geoserver rendered faster AND produced nicer looking renders.  Geoserver is also much easier to maintain with GUI for most features including integrated GeoWebCache.  Managing MapServer config files was painful, and I got zero benefit from it compared to GeoServer!  (In my experiment I was using CentOS and Shapefiles).

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a requirement to dynamically manipulate the images created by MapServer you should use the CGI application to server WMS requests. If not PHP will need to create all those objects in your code for every request, which if you are using tiles will be ~16 per map view.

You should also set mapserv.exe to run using FastCGI. See the instructions at http://www.ms4w.com/README_INSTALL.html#g-fastcgi

To take full advantage of FastCGI add the following to each layer that reads from a database:

```
PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
```

This will mean the database connection can be reused between requests, otherwise every layer may have to create, open, and close a database connection.