# Tile rendering time measurement in MapServer?

Tags: postgresql, mapserver, performance, tilecache

I try to speed up rendering time of tiles in mapserver app. How can I specify rendering engine in mapserver? The only thing about I found is: [outputformat](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/outputformat.html)

Tiles are generating very slow - about 4-5 sec (with postgres query - about 1,5 sec). 
How can I measure rendering time for tiles and what to do to speed up this process?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154137/mapserver-very-weak-performance-vs-geoserver-why. That Q also has a link to a stackoverflow Q on mapserver performance.

Answer (score 1):

For evaluating the rendering time, I usually use the "Network" tab of the Developer tool in Google Chrome (SHIFT + CTRL + I). When doing a mapserver request, you can see the time needed for each request:

[image: screen shot of network log]

To speed up the rendering, it depends on your layers and your map, but you can heavily speed up using some PROCESSING options in your [LAYER](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html), for instance PROCESSING "OVERSAMPLE_RATIO=1", PROCESSING "SCALE=a,b". You'll find some tips about raster data performance in mapserver on this [page](http://mapserver.org/input/raster.html#raster-display-performance-tips).

Of course, if your are able to better pre-process your data before rendering them with mapserver, it'll be better. For instance, if you work with vector data, make sure you have removed all unnecessary attributes and do some geometries smoothing (if you can afford it wrt your map requirements).